# Why Using COALESCE or CASE keep returning null

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following SQL Query :

```
(SELECT ROUND(SUM(NBTOSUM)/1000000,1) FROM MyTable t2 WHERE t2.ELEMNAME IN ('A','B','C'))
```

Which works fine.

But Where there is no `'A','B','C'` the result of the select is `(null)`

So to handle it, I did the following :

```
(SELECT COALESCE(ROUND(SUM(NBTOSUM)/1000000,1),0) FROM MyTable t2 WHERE t2.ELEMNAME IN ('A','B','C'))
```

And also try :

```
(SELECT 
 CASE
        WHEN SUM(NBTOSUM)/1000000 IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE ROUND(SUM(NBTOSUM)/1000000,1)
END 
FROM MyTable t2 WHERE t2.ELEMNAME IN ('A','B','C'))
```

But both keep returning `null`

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with the complete query you are using (yours currently has braces around it suggesting that you are using it as part of a larger query) and the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for some sample data that replicates the problem because it is difficult to replicate the issue you are having because your code **should** work ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/D1hmPna9)) and that suggests that your issue is elsewhere in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `WHERE` restrictions to the `CASE` expression as well:

```sql
SELECT ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN t2.ELEMNAME IN ('A','B','C')
                      THEN NBTOSUM ELSE 0 END) / 1000000, 1)
FROM MyTable t2;
```

Note that this trick solves the null problem and also avoids the need for an ugly `COALESCE()` call.

Comment: If the OP's code does not work, why should moving the `ELEMNAME` filter inside the `SUM` be any different? Can you generate a [MRE] where the OP's code does not work and this does? [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wl5HT3As)

Answer (score 1):

Your code **should** work as the `SUM` aggregation function will generate a single row of output regardless of whether the number of input rows is zero or non-zero. If there are no input rows or the values are all `NULL` then the output of the `SUM` will be `NULL` and then `COALESCE` would work.

Since you claim it does not then that suggests that there is something else going on in your query that you have not shared in the question.

---

You have braces around your statement suggesting that you are using it as part of a larger statement. If so, you can try moving the `COALESCE` to the outer query:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(
         (
           SELECT ROUND(SUM(NBTOSUM)/1000000,1)
           FROM   MyTable
           WHERE  ELEMNAME IN ('A','B','C')
         ),
         0
       )
FROM   your_outer_query;
```

That might fix the problem if you are somehow correlating to an outer query but your question makes no mention of that.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/D1hmPna9)